# 301 Redirect, Query string when there is no page in URL?

Tags: redirect, query-string

I can't quite get this one to work and I can't see an example that is helping me so I thought I'd ask.
Basically, I want to redirect www.mysite.co.uk/?cID=209 to www.mysite.co.uk/

Comment: Which framework you use or u using core-php ?

Comment: It's using Concrete5 CMS, written in core PHP